# Pyeve: How to have multiple date formats

Tags: python, eve

Seems like I can only specify global DATE_FORMAT in PyEve. How can I specify different formats for different fields within the same resource?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom data type to handle new formats. This is the example from documentation (https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/validation.html#custom-data-types):

```
def _validate_type_objectid(self, value):
    """ Enables validation for `objectid` schema attribute.

    :param value: field value.
    """
    if isinstance(value, ObjectId):
        return True
```

And then use the custom type in your schemas:

```
'schema': {
    'owner': {
        'type': 'objectid',
        'required': True,
    },
}
```